# Applications of sequences and series fish question

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is known that the number of fish in a given lake will decrease by 7% each year unless some new fish are added. At the end of each year, 250 new fish are added to the lake. At the start of 2018, there are 2500 fish in the lake.

Find the approximate number of fish in the lake at the start of 2042.

I attempted this question by calculating the common ratio = 2644.75/2575. I also calculated the number of years = 24.
I am stuck here. Any advise/comments on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just make a spreadsheet with a line for each year?  Apply your formula and copy down.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to know a formal process on how to solve these types of problems.

Comment: Then you should ask that.  You could see Wikipedia on [nonhomogeneous linear recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number of fishes in the lake at the start of year $2018+n$ be $a_n$. Given that
$$a_0=2500$$
$$a_{n+1}=250+0.93(a_n)$$
Can you proceed now?

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I understand the context of this question however I am now not sure where to proceed.

Comment: Try to generalise, $a_{n+1}=a+b(a_n)\Longrightarrow a_1=a+ba_0, a_2=a+b(a+ba_0)...$. Conjecture general formula for $n^{th}$ term and try induction.

Comment: I am assuming b represents 0.93. Does this imply that 0.93 is the common ratio? What do you mean by induction?

Comment: I am saying, $a_2=a(1+b)+b^2a_0, a_3=a(1+b+b^2)+b^3a_0...$. So it appears to follow a general formula. Try to guess general formula for $a_n$ and prove your guess by induction.

Comment: Thanks @Martund